# AngularJs: Is it possible to trigger one of directives methods from the main controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular directive i.e

```
.directive('multiselect', ['$document', '$rootScope', function ($document, $rootScope)
{
     link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        scope.toggleCheck = function (item) {
        ....
        }
     }
}
```

I need to trigger scope.toggleCheck from my main controller

Comment: just call it as `$scope.toggleCheck(item)` from the controller. it works. I did this way in my [ng-map](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps)

Answer (score 1):

One way you could achieve that is via an event sent through `$rootScope.$broadcast()`.

Your main controller could do:

`$rootScope.$broadcast('triggerToggle');`

And inside your directive, you could do:

```
scope.$on('triggerToggle', function(){
    // run your internal directive code here
});
```

Comment: I know that this portion get executed but if i try to print something inside .$on(...) nothing happens - what am I missing?

Comment: Thats the way I would do it too. No need to do it on $rootScope though. If a directive is a child of a controller, you only need to $broadcast on $scope

Comment: It does not get injected into the main controller so I have to stick with $rootScope